# Как в массиве чисел найти средний минимум и средний максимум?

Tags: php

Необходимо найти в массиве чисел **среднее значение** максимальных чисел и **среднее значение** минимальных чисел.

Нахожу максимум `$max = max($response);` - 75.27

Нахожу минимум `$min = min($response);` - 31.19

Нахожу среднее число `$sr = array_sum($response) / count($response);` - 55.31

Как найти **средний** максимум и минимум?

Получается мне известно максимальное, минимальное и среднее число из всех чисел.

Я понимаю, что необходимо сложить все числа больше `$sr` и меньше `$sr` далее поделить каждую сумму на количество чисел в сложении, тем самым получу средний минимум и средний максимум. Не понимаю как это реализовать.

$response:

```
Array
(
[24] => 39.812
[25] => 39.651
[26] => 40.673
[27] => 41.096
[28] => 41.556
[29] => 43.024
[30] => 43.767
[31] => 38.831
[32] => 37.042
[33] => 34.898
[34] => 33.954
[35] => 31.193
[36] => 32.619
[37] => 34.762
[38] => 36.561
[39] => 38.13
[40] => 45.557
[41] => 42.748
[42] => 46.327
[43] => 47.014
[44] => 44.99
[45] => 45.756
[46] => 46.555
[47] => 51.434
[48] => 51.152
[49] => 48.385
[50] => 49.465
[51] => 46.731
[52] => 50.797
[53] => 54.885
[54] => 56.34
[55] => 55.264
[56] => 56.575
[57] => 57.451
[58] => 57.873
[59] => 55.882
[60] => 58.053
[61] => 59.094
[62] => 65.601
[63] => 68.42
[64] => 74.06
[65] => 74.17
[66] => 75.27
[67] => 69.278
[68] => 68.747
[69] => 71.555
[70] => 73.506
[71] => 73.609
[72] => 68.627
[73] => 69.061
[74] => 64.681
[75] => 63.468
[76] => 64.814
[77] => 66.215
[78] => 62.616
[79] => 62.022
[80] => 61.414
[81] => 61.787
[82] => 69.706
[83] => 65.383
[84] => 61.665
[85] => 58.181
[86] => 55.63
[87] => 52.521
[88] => 54.116
[89] => 63.096
[90] => 68.346
[91] => 69.788
[92] => 71.889
[93] => 64.953
[94] => 66.553
[95] => 66.573
)
```

Comment: "Как найти средний максимум и минимум?" --- что такое средний максимум и средний минимум? Дайте определение пожалуйста.

Comment: У меня в массиве имеется среднее число 55.31 сложила все числа и поделила на их количество. Мне необходимо сложить все что выше 55.31 и поделить на количество этих чисел, таким образом я получу средний максимум... тоже сделать с числами меньше 55.31

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Начните с простого:

1. Заводите переменную счётчик
2. Заводите переменную суммы чисел
3. Пробегаетесь циклом по всему массиву
4. На каждой итерации смотрите, если текущее число массива больше среднего (55.31), то значение из переменной суммы складываете с текущим значением, а счётчик увелививаете на 1
5. После цикла поделите сумму на количество

---

Тоже самое  можно сделать со средним минимумом, только уже смотреть, что число **меньше** среднего